# Python / Pandas - Calculating ratio

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
bal:

             year   id   unit period          Revenues  Ativo Não-Circulante  \
business_id                                                                    
9564         2012  302  dsada  anual        5964168.52           10976013.70   
9564         2011  303  dsada  anual        5774707.15           10867868.13   
2361         2013  304  dsada  anual        3652575.31            6608468.52   
2361         2012  305  dsada  anual         321076.15            6027066.03   
2361         2011  306  dsada  anual        3858137.49            9733126.02   
2369         2012  307  dsada  anual         351373.66            9402830.89   
8104         2012  308  dsada  anual        3503226.02            6267307.01 
...
```

I want to create a column named "Growth". It would be the:

(Revenues from this year/Revenues from last year) - 1

The dataframe should look like this:

```
             year   id   unit period          Revenues               Growth  \
business_id                                                                    
9564         2012  302  dsada  anual        5964168.52                0.0328   
9564         2011  303  dsada  anual        5774707.15                   NaN   
2361         2013  304  dsada  anual        3652575.31                 10.37   
2361         2012  305  dsada  anual         321076.15                 -0.91   
2361         2011  306  dsada  anual        3858137.49                   NaN   
2369         2012  307  dsada  anual         351373.66                   NaN   
8104         2012  308  dsada  anual        3503226.02                   NaN 
...
```

How could I do that?

Comment: Methinks you need to create add/subtract one from the year and then join revenue to itself using this new year +/- 1 column and id to create next/last year's revenue. The calculation should be trivial after that.

Comment: @n8sty The solution is as obvious as you seem to think.  Although not well stated in the question, the annual growth in revenues is based on `business_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume your dataframe is named `df`. First rest your index so that `business_id` is a column, then sort the result on `year`.  Now group the dataframe on `business_id` and transform the result to get the percent change in revenues.  Finally, resort the index to get the original order.

```
df2 = df.reset_index().sort_values(['year'])
df2 = (
    df2
    .assign(Growth=df2.groupby(['business_id'])['Revenues'].transform(
        lambda group: group.pct_change()))
    .sort_index()
)
>>> df2
business_id year    id  unit    period  Revenues    Ativo Não-Circulante    Growth
0   9564    2012    302 dsada   anual   5964168.52  10976013.70           0.032809
1   9564    2011    303 dsada   anual   5774707.15  10867868.13                NaN
2   2361    2013    304 dsada   anual   3652575.31  6608468.52           10.376041
3   2361    2012    305 dsada   anual   321076.15   6027066.03           -0.916779
4   2361    2011    306 dsada   anual   3858137.49  9733126.02                 NaN
5   2369    2012    307 dsada   anual   351373.66   9402830.89                 NaN
6   8104    2012    308 dsada   anual   3503226.02  6267307.01                 NaN
```

I think you have an error in your expected output:

```
5964168.52 / 5774707.15 - 1 = 0.0328  # vs. 0.16 shown.
```

Comment: Great solution. In fact I have miscalculated it in the question. I will edit and fix it. Thanks @Alexander

Answer (score 0):

You need to "groupby" year and "sort_values" by year loop through groupby values to calculate growth, store the growth in list and convert to numpy.array(growth), add to dataframe.

```
#df is your dataframe 
group = df.groupby(df['year']) 
R =  {} #Store Revenue in dictionary 
y = [] #make list of year to append years
for year, values in group:
    R[year] = values[Revenues]
    y.append(year)
g = [] #create list of growth
for i, eyear in enumerate(y):
    try:
       g.append(eyear[i]/eyear[i+1])
    except:
       pass
df['Growth'] = numpy.array(g) #Create numpy array and append to df
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a `groupby('business_id')`, then a [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to get the last year's revenues.  Save that off to a new column, then do the ratio, like so:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)   # You might have to do this because it looks like your index is 'business_id'

df['Previous Revenues'] = df.sort_values('year').groupby('business_id')['Revenues'].shift(1)
df['Growth'] = df['Revenues']/df['Previous Revenues'] - 1
```

If you want, you don't need to save the new column, but the line gets a little messy:

```
 df['Growth'] = df['Revenues']/df.sort_values('year').groupby('business_id')['Revenues'].shift(1) - 1
```